# Web design issues on Askubuntu

Tags: discussion, bug, firefox

Whenever I try to add a new favorite tag on Askubuntu that is on the right side of the website the button `add` seems to be cut/trimmed. Is this issue with my Firefox or it's a website issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a bug with mostly all the SE sites as I at some point reported [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253640/favorite-tag-buttons-partly-sticking-off-page).

Comment: ah, I see it now clear. Thanks.